# How to assign items selected in listbox into each cell with For statement

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, userform

I am going to use listbox to allow users to multiselect. However, I have no idea to put them items selected into each cell in a column. Here are my codes. I get stuck in the For statement as I know that it run go through the inner loop and then the outer loop. Anyone can help...Thanks

```
Private Sub lbaspectc_AfterUpdate()

For Each selected In Me.listbox.ItemsSelected

    For Each c3 In Worksheets("maintenance").Range(Cells(2, 7), Cells(, 7))  'Here i would like to start filling in from cell G2. I am not sure if the syntax is correct'

        c3.Value = selected.Value
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this? You'll need to re-assign to the correct control.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Long, j As Long

j = 2

With Me.ListBox1
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) Then
            Worksheets("maintenance").Cells(j, 7).Value = .List(i)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly. Thank you very much:)

Comment: Hi SJR, may i have a further questionon  the IF statement "If .Selected(i) Then". What is the condition in this IF statement? As I normally see IF will be followed by some test (eg. IF x <> 1).

Comment: Yes it’s shorthand for ‘If .Selected(i)=True’.